# iOS SCNSceneView snapshot resolution

Tags: scenekit

I have created an iOS application in swift 3.
I define the size of the SCNSceneView at run time with this code:

```
my_scene_view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 300, height:200)
```

When i am calling snapshot function on my_scene_view, i am expecting a UIImage with 300x200 size but i get 1843x1382

Is there a way to force resolution when taking snapshot ?

Thanks

Comment: are you taking the snapshot right after changing the view's frame? If so, have you tried to `SCNTransaction.flush()` between the two?

Comment: In fact i am taking the snapshot randomly by pressing a button so i am not synchronized